# Stuck on Django 4.2.11

Tags: python, django

I try to learn Django but I came across a wall.
I need to use Django 5 for my project but when I update Django to 5.0.3 my terminal update it than say that I am still in 4.2.11.

So I tried to uninstall it then reinstall it but after a successfull uninstallation the command : "python -m django --version" still return the 4.2.11 version.

So what can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Well exacthy how did you reinstall, did you install other packages that might impose constraints on the Django version?

Comment: To clarify, that's what I mean :
"Last login: Tue Mar 19 21:12:03 on ttys001
(base) clement@MacBook-Air ~ % django --version
zsh: command not found: django
(base) clement@MacBook-Air ~ % django-admin --version
5.0.3
(base) clement@MacBook-Air ~ % python -m django --version
4.2.11"

Answer (score 0):

Try these three steps:

1. Uninstalling Django and then installing it again
2. Make sure the pip is up-to-date: pip install --upgrade pip
3. Try creating a virtual environment (recommended whenever working with Django projects).Now within the environment try installing django: pip install django==5.0.3

Hope it helps

Comment: the commands are for windows, in case of linux or mac use their commands instead.